# Pandas: Rename duplicate columns in same dataframe and merge

Tags: pandas

I have the following;

```
mylist = ["name", "state", "name", "city"]
newlist = ["name1", "state", "name2", "city"]
```

I have renamed the duplicates. I would like to merge the `name1` and `name2` and rename to name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Can you provide a small snippet of your input dataframe and expected output?

Comment: I have column names ["name", "state", "name", "city"] and I have renamed to ["name1", "state", "name2", "city"]. I want to merges name1 and name 2 and then rename to Name. Hope I am clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This method works well to do this and is clean:

Renamed DataFrame method accepts the dictionary "key: values" that allow you to map the old value to the new value.

Example.

```
new_df = "read in data source"

col_map = {"name": "name1",
    "state": "state",
    "name": "name2",
    "city": "city"
}

new_df.rename(columns=col_map)
```

This method should work perfectly fine. Please respond so that our team here in StackOverflow knows that you care about our feedback and are responsive.